# How to use mouse in SpookyJS?

Tags: node.js, casperjs, spookyjs

How to use mouse in SpookyJS?
In CasperJS I can use mouse:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var mouse = require("mouse").create(casper);
```

How can I do it with SpookyJS?

Comment: `this.mouse` inside the casper context maybe?

Answer (score 0):

To access any Casper prototypes in its module, including other CasperJS modules, you have to do it inside the CasperJS scope.

As explained on https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS/wiki/Introduction :

```
//this is nodejs environement
//declare your spooky instance here
spooky.start('http://example.com/the-page.html');
spooky.then(function () {
    // this function runs in Casper's environment
    //here you can access to mouse module. Example :
    this.mouse.click(400, 300); 
});
spooky.thenEvaluate(function () {
    // this function runs in the page's environment
})
// this function (and the three spooky calls above) runs in Spooky's environment
spooky.run();
```